# Differentiating the norm of a vector

Tags: differential-geometry

How do you differentiate

$|\alpha(s)|^2$ given that $\alpha$ is a vector. The $\frac{d^2}{ds^2}(|\alpha(s)|^2)$ = ?

However from the above we get the following result:

$\alpha(s) = -Rn + R'Tb$. Given that $R=1/k$,  $T=1/\tau$, $R' = \frac{d}{ds} (R)$

I'm not entirely sure how you get there. If it is too long, can you just tell me the first part at least since I'm not even sure how to differentiate the norm of a vector. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

$$|\alpha(s)|^2=\alpha_1(s)^2+...+\alpha_n(s)^2$$

$$\implies \left( |\alpha(s)|^2 \right)'(t)=2\alpha_1(t)\alpha_1'(t)+...+2\alpha_n(t)\alpha_n'(t)=2\langle \alpha(t) , \alpha'(t)\rangle$$

Alternative way $1$:

Prove that $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle '(t)=\langle \alpha(t),\beta'(t) \rangle+\langle \alpha '(t), \beta(t) \rangle. $ This should be an easy calculation (see the first way). Note also that this is the product rule.

Alternative way $2$:

Define $f(t)=|\alpha(t)|^2$

$$f(t)=\langle \alpha(t), \alpha(t) \rangle \implies f(t+h)=\langle \alpha(t+h), 
\alpha(t+h) \rangle $$

$$=\langle \alpha(t)+ \alpha '(t).h +\epsilon(h) , \alpha(t)+ \alpha '(t).h +\epsilon_1(h)  \rangle$$
$$=f(t)+\langle 2\alpha(t), \alpha'(t).h \rangle + \epsilon_2(h)$$

Since $f'(t)=Df_t(1)$, we have that $f'(t)=2 \langle \alpha(t),\alpha'(t)\rangle$

Yet another way:

Chain Rule. Since the derivative of the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ at $x$ is $\langle 2x, \cdot \rangle$, the derivative of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \circ \alpha$ is $2 \langle \alpha(t),  \alpha '(t)\rangle$.

Now, using Alternative Way $1$*, we have:

$$\left( |\alpha(s)|^2 \right)''(t)=\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle''(t)=2\langle \alpha, \alpha' \rangle'(t)=2\langle \alpha'(t), \alpha'(t) \rangle+2\langle\alpha(t),\alpha''(t) \rangle$$

*Note that the other Ways can also prove Alternative Way $1$ quite analogously.